# How does Youtube plays video with sound on mobile Safari if Apple block autoplay with sound?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, mobile-safari

As per [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari#3030251) autoplay only works if the video is muted. But for some reason on [Youtube](https://m.youtube.com) when I open a video from the homepage, it starts automatically (without touching anything on the screen) with sound. How did Youtube implement this functionality?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Wondering the same thing.

Comment: As I saw on Youtube, on every page there is a video element included, hidden in some pages(ex. homepage) but still included in the DOM. If you interact with the site, it will interact with the video element too, thats why the video can start with sound on right away. I'm not 100% sure, but possibly this is how they managed to do it.